# Explain the main function of different capabilities of the Firefox extension NoScript 11.4.22

Tags: firefox, extension, noscript

## About NoScript

My understanding of [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) is that it allows the user to decide what scripts a website can execute. I want to learn more about the different *capabilities* (shown later) that can be toggled by NoScript.

## Modes of NoScript

In the browser extension page, it shows that NoScript has 3 modes: Default, Trusted, Untrusted. All modes have the capacity to enable or disable the following *capabilities*:

- script
- object
- media
- frame
- font
- webgl
- fetch
- ping
- noscript
- unrestricted CSS
- LAN
- other

## What I want to learn about these capabilities

I am already familiar with the following capabilities: `noscript`, `LAN`, `webgl`, `font`

These are the capabilities that I want to learn more about:

- `script`
- `object`
- `media`
- `frame`
- `fetch`
- `ping`
- `unrestricted CSS`
- `other`

I want to learn about the main function of each capability to further understand their significance.

## What I've tried so far

- I have read the following sections of NoScript:

  - [What is it?](https://noscript.net/)
  - [Usage](https://noscript.net/usage/)
  - [FAQ](https://noscript.net/faq/)

None of these sections specifically talked about the significance and functions of each capability

- searched [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) using the following queries:

  - noscript capabilities
  - firefox noscript extension capabilities
  - noscript extension capabilities
  - noscript extension modes
  - what does noscript do
  - what does the noscript extension do

None of these queries showed me results that talk about the different *capabilities* in NoScript

## More Information

Browser: Firefox Browser 114.0.1 (64-bit)

NoScript version: 11.4.22

Comment: Hello, please ask a **specific** question else this will get closed due to lack of focus. You ask not only about 8 different parts of software, but also split that into 3 parts.

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question to only focus on explaining the main function of the selected capabilities.

Comment: This is still a lot. Did you see https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?p=103816#p103816 also?

Comment: @Destroy666 I didn't see this page. This answers my question, so can you please post it as an answer, so I can mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list [here](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?p=103816#p103816) about all these options:

> - `script` - JavaScript, e.g. `<script>` tags
> - `object` - plugin objects (usually Flash, Java applets, Silverlight, etc)
> - `media` - HTML5 audio/video
> - `frame` - subdocuments, e.g. `<frame>` and `<iframe>`
> - `fetch` - whether other sites can make [`XMLHttpRequest` (sometimes abbreviated as "XHR")](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/XMLHttpRequest) and [`Fetch` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to this site
> - `ping` - destination of [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) and hyperlink ping attribute
> - `unrestricted CSS` - when disabled for a site, NoScript mitigates pure-CSS exploits (e.g. [CSS PP0](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=26263)) on pages served by that site
> - `other` - requests where Firefox cannot identify the request type ([ref](https://hackademix.net/2017/12/04/noscript-quantum-vs-legacy-in-a-nutshell-2/#comment-39964))